# Developing for iPad 2

Tags: ios, c, xcode, ipad

I want to start learning about creating apps/games on the iPad 2. I cannot find hardly anything about iPad 2 although I have found lots of resources for iPad 1 development. Basically, I want to ask if I was to create an iPad 1 application, can it be deployed onto iPad 2 for testing/debugging/release no questions asked?

Also, am I able to use other frameworks which allow me to use Java, C# or C++? if so, can you recommend anything?

Thanks very much,

Jamie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not much difference between iPad 1 and 2. You should target both devices (as long as you don't need the few extras on iPad 2 like camera for example).

All iPad 1 software will run on iPad 2.

Edit: No native Java or C# on iOS, although there might be some projects making them work - but it's rather "hackyish".  C++ is of course just fine, as is C.

Comment: Brilliant, is there anything you can recommend for using c++? or would it be easier just to stick with Xcode ?

Comment: Xcode all the way. C++ (or Objective-C++) is a good choice if you don't want to go all Obj-C.

Answer (score 0):

iPad, iPad 2, iPod touch, and iPhone all use iOS. Other than possible issues like "Oh, I assumed a resolution here that doesn't hold true for this device...", programming for one is the same as programming for another.

This is especially true for the iPad and the iPad 2, since they are very similar pieces of hardware. I wouldn't be surprised if an iPad program worked perfectly on the iPad 2 without any adjustments.

As for java, etc., sorry, Apple doesn't want to make anything too easy. You have to stick with C++ or, preferably, Objective C (since Objective C comes with a lot of iOS specific functions.)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Eiko's answer, [Monotouch](http://monotouch.net/) is a very popular framework for .NET development on iOS devices.

Comment: Monotouch seems to improve. Are there still problems with getting apps approved that are written in "non-C" languages?

Comment: According to [this statement](http://www.apple.com/pr/library/2010/09/09statement.html), there are no longer any restrictions on the 'original' language used to write the app, providing it compiles for iOS and doesn't break Apple's many other policies!

Comment: Ah thank you! Definitely nice to read, and the Unity guys are now safe, too.

Answer (score 0):

I would very, very strongly recommend using Objective-C and the Cocoa Touch frameworks as the basis for your app. UIKit is excellent at getting good looking, well performing UI quickly, and Xcode provides very nice development tools.

The iPad 2 is like the iPad 1, except that it's faster and has cameras, basically. Build for iPad 1 and you shouldn't expect any problems.

EDIT: Learn Objective-C and the Frameworks, it's not hard and provides great results. A very good book for people who know object-oriented programming and want to learn Objective-C and Cocoa Touch is *IPhone Programming: The Big Nerd Ranch Guide*. Despite being targeted at iPhone development, its examples can be built for iPad with nearly zero changes (and by the time you get to a chapter where you need to make slight changes, you'lll know how to). Programming for iPhone and iPad are very nearly the same, with some differences in the availability of certain UI elements (and of course resolution and GUI/UX paradigm), as someone else already pointed out. This book will teach you the basics you won't instantly get from Apple's excellent documentation, and explain the reasoning behind certain pattern choices.